# Which android component should decide rather user is logged in or not?

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

I would like to implement user authentication flow. I have login and main activities. But which component should decide rather user is logged in and redirect to proper activity? I know about AccountManager but what component should call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using third party login(google, facebook, etc) authenticate user on launch activity and redirect accordingly.

For example, **LaunchActivity** starts on app launch, in LaunchActivity

```
onCreate(...){
    ...
    if(isUserLoggedIn){
        //go to MainActivity
    } else {
        //go to LoginActivity
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Deval. Thanks for reply. Will this activity be visible to the user?

Comment: No it won't be visible, unless you authenticate user on any other event( like authenticating user login on button click or something)

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use shared preferences and save boolean value in it.
if your user is login successfully then save true in sharedpreferences otherwise false.
then on your activity get value from shared preferences like this

```
boolean checkUserLogin = yourSharedPrefObject.getUserLoginCheck("yourshareprefKey");
if(checkUserLogin){
   //do some code
 }
else
{
  //do some code
}
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Unzila. Thanks for reply. As I know sharedpreferences doesn't enough secure.

Comment: i know its not secure , you only safe true false in it. not main information, this check is only good for your logic to call specific activity which you want to call.